# Why is MessageDigest returning different answers for the same string?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a hash value for a string using MessageDigest in Java, but the value is different every time. When I run the program twice it will again have completely different answers.

```
        MessageDigest md = null;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        }

        md.update("string".getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        System.out.println(digest);

        md.reset();

        md.update("string".getBytes());
        byte[] digest2 = md.digest();
        System.out.println(digest2);
```

Comment: Also note that `MessageDigest#reset()` is automatically called with 'MessageDigest#digest()'. [(see Javadoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest())

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are outputting the `byte[]` object, not the byte array contents. Use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digest1));
....
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digest2));
```

Comment: How can I output the content? I think I have missed the .toString() part but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, added the code a bit too late :) `Arrays` is `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: Just to clarify: `digest1` (or `digest2`) has the type `byte[]` which  inherits the `Object`'s `toString()` implementation: it outputs the mangled object type and its hashCode. This is what you were getting originally.